# mutating array with forEach

Tags: arrays, foreach, dplyr

I'm tasked to write a forEach method that mutates string values for each element in the array.

Here's an example:

```
candy = ['snickers', 'mars', 'three muskateers']

candy.forEach(function(e){
  e.toUpperCase());
});
```

I tested out the forEach by console logging and it appears I'm getting the return values I want.

```
candy.forEach(function(e){
  console.log(e.toUpperCase());
```

However, when I print the array to confirm that the original array has changed, I get the original array back.

```
console.log(candy);
```

Does this have to do with strings are primitive data types? Can someone please help me better understand?

Comment: You need to assign the new value to each array element, toUpperCase won't change the original element

Answer (score 1):

When you tried to print the `candy` array, you didn't receive any changes because both `map` and `forEach` functions doesn't affect/modify the original array.

Using **`forEach`**:

```js
candy = ['snickers', 'mars', 'three muskateers'];

console.log(candy.forEach(v => v.toUpperCase()));

console.log(candy);
```

Using **`map`** function:

```js
candy = ['snickers', 'mars', 'three muskateers'];

console.log(candy.map(v => v.toUpperCase()));

console.log(candy);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Hovewer, you can notice that `forEach` function returns `undefined` because `forEach` doesn't return anything. It just performs given action on the array, while the `map` function returned brand new array with modified elements.

Because of the fact that the `forEach` function aswell as `map` doesn't modify the original array, if you wish to change the original array, you can do it by assigning the modified array by the `map` function to your `candy` variable.

```js
candy = ['snickers', 'mars', 'three muskateers'];

candy = candy.map(v => v.toUpperCase());

console.log(candy);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

**Note**, that if you would use `forEach` here, `console.log(candy)` would return `undefined`.

```js
candy = ['snickers', 'mars', 'three muskateers'];

candy = candy.forEach(v => v.toUpperCase());

console.log(candy);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The original array isn't getting modified in your case.

You need to create a separate array and store the uppercase values inside the for each in the separate array.

Your Code(modified):

```
candy = ['snickers', 'mars', 'three muskateers']
var candyModified = Array();
candy.forEach(function(e){
    candyModified.push(e.toUpperCase());
});
console.log(candyModified);
```

Answer (score 0):

To modify it, you have to use 3rd argument of `forEach` or use `candy` itself. Like this:

#### Method 1 - 3rd arg

```js
candy = ['snickers', 'mars', 'three muskateers']

candy.forEach(function(el, i, arr){
  arr[i] = el.toUpperCase();
});

console.log(candy);
```

#### Method 2 - use `candy`

```js
candy = ['snickers', 'mars', 'three muskateers']

candy.forEach(function(el, i){
  candy[i] = el.toUpperCase();
});

console.log(candy);
```